# How to change text color in Arena Chess?

Tags: arena

I am trying to create a dark color scheme for **Arena** but the problem is that the text inside the analysis pane – the area below the chessboard – is hard to read. How can I change the color of this text?
[image]
I am using Arena 3.5.1 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in **Arena** some colors are controlled by the operating system. I went to **Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Personalization**, clicked on **Window Color** and in the **Window Color and Appearance** I changed the color of the item **Window** to green in order to make it easier to see the color changes in **Arena**.[image]

And this is the result.
[image]

As you can see, some text remained black, like:

- RAM display (next to the Appearance Settings button)
- players' rating
- numbers inside the **Permanent Statistics** pane
- last player move (to the right of opening name)
- the **Demo** button

I don't know how to change the color of these elements.